# Catch Lambda timeout

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

Probably a newbie question:

(I know that there is gettimeremaining property in context).

I have a job that is querying an API (say Marketo), however I need to plan for the scenario where the API does not return the required data in 15 mins.

I can check the remaining time in ms from context, however how do i accomplish this along with my data pull tasks as 2 concurrent tasks?

Meaning, do I fire off something first that says keep check of time, and then i proceed to my actual work and when time is 14 mins the first thing/thread returns back and I can proceed accodingly?

Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, so according to my understanding, 
Your lambda is querying an API and also storing the data from that API at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, correct. i am querying an EndPOint and storing the data after it is retrieved.

Comment: And you must be querying endpoint not on 1 condition but based on different conditions which are more than 1, right ?

Comment: I am just pulling all data for the past 1 year. I will break it down to chunk, but my question was generic, so that I know how to solve for this in any situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling an external API you will be using a client to make a connection; set connection timeout to be less than maximum time you can wait. In-case API doesn't return response in time your connection with throw timeout exception which than you can handle gracefully.

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts